# Run script on button click only if specific cell numerical value has increase or decreased

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the script below the works just fine. I assigned it to a button drawing in google sheets that runs the script when the button is clicked. I would like to still run the script when the button is clicked but only if the CELL X1 numerical value has changed by increasing or decreasing. Does any one have an idea how to go about doing that?

```
function copy(){
 var t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');


var pp = t.getSheetByName('UP');

var ppk = pp.getRange(1,1,pp.getLastRow(),pp.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var data = []                       
for (var i = 0; i< ppk.length ; i++){
if(ppk[i][24] == "Yes")        
{
data.push(ppk[i])
}
}


var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


var sp = s.getSheetByName('down');
sp.getRange(1,1,sp.getLastRow(),sp.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
sp.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);  

sp.deleteColumns(19, 7);

}
```

Comment: You could keep the old value in PropertiesService.

Comment: i think i found a work around. How would I get it to check the value of a current cell and if that cell is not to lets say the value "GO" it will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Example using PropertiesService

```
var turnsoleCell = 'Sheet1!A3'; // The cell in question

function checkUpdateRequired(){
  var lastValue = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('lastTurnsole');
  var currentValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(turnsoleCell).getValue();
  if(lastValue != currentValue){
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('lastTurnsole', currentValue);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```